# Bootstrap missing top accordion border when accordion-items hidden

Tags: jquery, border, accordion, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 accordion component on my page. I also have a JavaScript snippet that makes one or multiple accordion-items of this accordion hide depending on user search.

When the top accordion-idem is hidden, visible accordion-items underneath it have a missing top border. Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement. You might as well ask your auto mechanic to fix your car and leave the car at home. :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when I put a 10px margin between my accordion items. The top border was missing on every item after the first, because they are designed to share a border between themselves. I am not sure if this is the best solution, but adding a border-top of 1px on the accordion item class fixed it for me, and now every accordion item had a full border!